# How to turn off Pathfinding in navmesh unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use navmesh agent for my Isometric game (diablo like)
how then in all diablo-projects did they make it possible to rest against the wall?
how to off pathfind in nav mesh agent ?
I just want to hit the wall (or game object)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAfra.png)
[ExampleInPoe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SnI9.jpg)

I tried everything, I can't figure out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `NavmeshObstacles` like explained here https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/navigation-basics#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b49c in Step 5.

So your navmesh basically ignores the wall - but the object prevents the player from passing. During runtime you can just remove the object and the path will be walkable.

Update:
In order to force the player to run into the wall (I assume when you say 'rest' against the wall you mean that), you could add a script that recognizes the player when they're close and then takes over their movement to let them smash the wall.

But this isn't a specific question anymore. So I'd rather recommend that you check out the Unity Tutorial section: https://learn.unity.com/search?k=%5B%22tag%3A5d351f087fbf7d006af48180%22%5D And try to get a better understanding of navigation and player movement in general.